# How to convert - values in 0 an array to integer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My array consists of - values as shown below
[-41.23,-34.23,-0.98576]

wanted all the - values to replace /convert to 0 using JavaScript
Let me know if  there is any way to achieve this

Comment: Yes, there is a way to achieve this. Actually, more than just one, of course. If you are not familiar with stuff like `Array.map` yet, then you should at least be able to write a simple _loop_ over all the elements yourself, no? IMHO you need to show a bit more effort here.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple `map` suggestion:

```
let arr = [-41.23,-34.23,-0.98576];
let newArr = arr.map(val => val.toString().replace('-', '0'));
// newArr = ["041.23", "034.23", "00.98576"]
```

The values in `newArr` are strings, since JS removes leading zeros for numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean negative values ​​and you could do something like this:

```
var a = [-2, 3, -5, 8];

for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  if(a[i]<0){
    a[i] = 0;
  }
}
```